# SCANTOOL cable giving errors BUS and CAN when connecting to a TOYOTA

Tags: toyota

I have installed obdwiz software on windows 7  and connected the Usb scantool cable  to the vehicle but am getting BUS and CAN error.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to get the software that is coded precisely to your vehicle - I have a jaguar and alot of the generic (read cheap) readers will not work at all or have limited functionality. My one comes from Icarsoft and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question properly we need to know what model and year your vehicle is and what cable/hardware you are using.

It sounds like you have a purely CAN bus based interface but your vehicle does not support CAN bus diagnostics.

If this is not the case check your connections and settings, check fuses and then check you have 12v at pin16 of the OBD plug.